# How to detect if var is a string

Tags: c#, string, variables, if-statement, detect

I am having a bit of trouble using an if statement to detect if my numericupdown object is a string so I don't use a decimal variable to adjust it. I saw there was a type of commmand, but I am having trouble using it. Here is what I am looking at:

```
if(typeof sentNUD.Value == string)
{
       //Do string arguments here
}
else
{
        //do decimal arguments here
}
```

The syntax of the if statement is wrong though and I get an error. How do I set up that if statement correctly? I tried looking around a bit, but I am having trouble understanding how to do this correctly. Thank you.

Comment: Consider downloading the C# specification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (sentNUD.Value.GetType() == typeof(string))
{
// string stuff
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use the "is"-operator:

```
if(variable is string)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should you use the method's static overloading to work your solution ??

The use of "typeOf" is normaly frowned by OO purists.